# How to get the mindate of a date that is stored as an int in dbt + snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I am working with DBT + SNOWFLAKE.

I have a column called "Event_Name", which is a date that comes as an int.

> 20230101

I've made the following model and I've tested it with hardcoded dates to make sure I got the function right.
However, when I want to point the start_date to the min Event_Date, I get the following error:

```
17:18:04  252005: Failed to convert current row, cause: Python int too large to convert to C int
```

This is the model:

```
{{ config(
      alias='DIM_DATE',
      materialized = "table"
) }}

{% set get_min_date_query %}
    select min(event_date::varchar) 
    from  {{ ref('raw_events_pivot') }}
{% endset %}
{% set min_query_result = run_query(get_min_date_query) %}

{% if execute %}
 {% set min_year_result = min_query_result.columns[0].values()[0] %}
{% else %}
    set min_year_result = 0
{% endif %}  
{% set start_date =  get_start_date(min_year_result ) %}
 

with date_create as (
{{ dbt_date.get_date_dimension( start_date ,  '2023-12-31' )}}
) 

SELECT
    DATE_DAY AS date,
    YEAR_NUMBER as year,
    DAY_OF_WEEK_NAME_SHORT as day_name,
    WEEK_OF_YEAR,
    'WK' || WEEK_OF_YEAR || '-' || YEAR_NUMBER as week_year, --WK52-2022
    MONTH_OF_YEAR as month_nr,
    MONTH_NAME,
    MONTH_NAME_SHORT,
    QUARTER_OF_YEAR as quarter,
    'Q'|| QUARTER_OF_YEAR  || '-' || YEAR_NUMBER AS quarter_year, --Q1-2023
    current_user() as INT_LoadBy,
    sysdate()  as INT_UPDATETIMESTAMPUTC,
    'DBT' as COD_IntSourceSystem
FROM Date
```

What am I supposed to do to fix this?
I even tried to convert the start date to char but I didn't get it...

Comment: I don't know dbt at all, but have you tried converting the integer to a date?  In Snowflake SQL, it'd be something like `TO_DATE(event_date,'YYYYMMDD')` but I'm not sure how that translates to dbt.

Comment: what are you trying to do ? if you want mindate, you should write a simple sql `select min(event_date) as mindtINT  from   {{ ref('raw_events_pivot') }}`. And then use this INT value anywhere. I cant figure out what you are trying to do. Pls can you explain sample input, output and logic.

Comment: that is the problem. If I do the simple sql, I get the error: '''invalid type [TO_DATE(RAW_EVENTS_PIVOT.EVENT_DATE)] for parameter 'TO_DATE' ''' and if I convert event_date to ::varchar, it  gives me the error: Timestamp '1970-08-23-01-01' is not recognized

Comment: @MikeWalton if I do that directly, it says that it cannot convert it because it expects a string and my event_date is an int. But when I try to convert it to varchar before converting it to date, it says  Timestamp '1970-08-23-01-01' is not recognized

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast to a VARCHAR then to Date:

```
select to_date(20230101::VARCHAR, 'YYYYMMDD');
```

Comment: I've also done that. And I got 
15:15:06  Database Error in model dim_date (models\Integration\dim_date.sql)
15:15:06    100035 (22007): Timestamp '(datetime.date(2023, 3, 8),)' is not recognized

Comment: What is `get_start_date()`? And I assume your from clause is supposed to be `date_create` not `date`. I've taken your model and replaced the `get_min_date_query` with the static select I put in my answer, changed the line with `get_start_date` to `{% set start_date =  min_year_result %}` and fixed the from clause and the model ran fine. That means you have an issue with your data (which isn't posted) and you probably have invalid integers in the results set. If you can add a minimal resultset with the `raw_events_pivot` data that is causing the issue, I can help more.